# Python and QsystemTray application

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5, system-tray

I have a code which runs on KDE system very well.
On Unity (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) this code produces unexpected result. 
Result on Unity:
[wrong result on Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lZ5D.png)

Bus the same code produces good result on KDE system:
[Link to a good result](http://p.im9.eu/hf3262.jpg)
Question: Why the same code does not work on Unity?
And a code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)

        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(parent)
        edit.setText("Tekstas kuris turi būti atsiradęs čia")

        hl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(parent)
        hl.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Testuojame"))
        hl.addWidget(edit)

        w = QtGui.QWidget(parent)
        w.setLayout(hl)

        wa = QtGui.QWidgetAction(parent)
        wa.setDefaultWidget(w)
        menu.addAction(wa)

       exitAction = menu.addAction("Blabla")
       exitAction = menu.addAction("Blabla 2")

       self.setContextMenu(menu)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons/close.png"), w)

    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the same behaviour on KDE 5.26.0 (Qt 5.6.1, Ubuntu 16.10), the `defaultWidget` is not shown in the context menu, only the (empty) `iconText` of the QWidgetAction is displayed. The way the context menu is shown is ultimately controlled by the tray (which is specific to the used desktop environment).

To get this to work consitently you can show your menu as a popup menu on activation instead of in the context menu. The difference is that it isn't activated on right click but on left click and that it may look different from the native trays context menu.

Your example would then look like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, icon, parent)

        self.menu = menu = QtGui.QMenu()
        edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        edit.setText("Tekstas kuris turi būti atsiradęs čia")

        w = QtGui.QWidget()
        hl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(hl)
        hl.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Testuojame"))
        hl.addWidget(edit)

        wa = QtGui.QWidgetAction(menu)
        wa.setDefaultWidget(w)
        menu.addAction(wa)

        exitAction = menu.addAction("Blabla")
        exitAction = menu.addAction("Blabla 2")

        self.activated.connect(self.showPopupMenu)

    def showPopupMenu(self, reason):
        if reason == QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.Trigger:
            self.menu.popup(QtGui.QCursor.pos())



def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    trayIcon = SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons/close.png"))
    trayIcon.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: uhm, nope. I have got using this code just a grey rectangle near to Systemtray icon.